# Cassandra : Does deleting a whole partition create tombstone?

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

I'm new to Cassandra. I had a situation where delete per partition is performed. Does deleting the entire partition create tombstones? Right now space is not getting released after the deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, deletion of the whole partition creates a special type of the tombstone that "shadows" the all data in the partition.  But like the other tombstones, it's kept for gc_grace_seconds, and only after that collected.

There is a [great blog post](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) from the The Last Pickle that explains tombstones in great details

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the tombstones completely? we were planning for a hard delete for a particular partition [data that are no longer needed]

Comment: No - tombstones are the way, Cassandra and other distributed systems make sure that the data is actually deleted, and not resurrected.  You can shorten the cycle, if you make sure that all data is repaired, then you temporarily decrease the `gc_grace_seconds`, do compaction, and restore `gc_grace_seconds` - but you really need to make sure that data is repaired before & after that

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can update gc_grace_seconds to 0 but I wouldn't recommend that unless you only have one node in your cluster or that your RF=1. You could try to reduce GC grace to an acceptable time for you. I'd like to put the maximum time I think a Cassandra node could stay down.

An other option to immediately releasing space is to change your data model to use truncate/drop. For instance if you only need your data for 24h you could create one table per day and at some point drop the tables that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I made test with insert new data after delete by the same partition key.

```
create table message_routes (
  user_id bigint,
  route_id bigint,
  primary key ((user_id), service_id)
)
```

1. `insert into message_routes (user_id, route_id) values (1, 2)`
2. `delete from message_routes where user_id = 1`
3. `insert info message_routes (user_Id, route_id) values (1, 3)`

After each stage was executed nodetool flush & nodetool compact but tombstone from stage 2 was't evicted as shown by sstablemetadata. After delete was executed new insert. I was hoping that Cassandra has optimizations for such cases.

It's interesting how this tombstones affect select queries by partition key if delete will be frequents?

```
select * from message_routes where user_id = 1
```

Comment: partition tombstone will affect performance only if you're doing the full table scan... Regarding the optimization - your use case doesn't cover the situation when you had multiple rows in the partition that needs to be deleted.  See the blog post that I linked

Comment: I read that blog and add question to it
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html#comment-5326200486